# How do I put this in a for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I would like to put the following to a for loop. How do I do this since we haven't studied arrays yet. My instructor would like me to put the quarters 1-4 to a for loop.

````
quarter = 1;
interest = principal * quarterlyRate; // item 5
finalAmount = principal + interest;
System.out.printf("%6s%8d%16.2f%30.2f%n", year, quarter, interest, finalAmount);```
````

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Something like `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { interest = principal * quarterlyRate; principal += interest; }`? I'll leave it to you to work out how to do the `printf()`.

Comment: I'm sorry for this but I can't put the whole code in the question :((

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

````
# looping here
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
   interest = principal * quarterlyRate; // item 5
   finalAmount = principal + interest;
   System.out.printf("%6s%8d%16.2f%30.2f%n", year, i, interest, finalAmount);```
}
````

Comment: Thank you!! I'll take a look into it.

Comment: It works, so the quarter was turned into the i in the sysout statement. I'll definitely make use of this knowledge in the future.

Comment: Then, set it as the answer by checking it.